# Kentico - How to display data from the Uni Selector in the MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, kentico, kentico-mvc

I want to display the `Uni Selector` field from one of the pages in the `.cshtml` file. Now I have the controller and everything else added **(can show for example title of the page, image etc.)**. Now, I am struggling with displaying those fields from the Uni Selector selected items. Basically, I have the folder where all my lets say **cards** are stored. And I added the field `Uni Selector` in the page itself, so that the page has those cards that are selected (not every card, of course only those that are selected). How to show those fields from those cards that are selected in the `Uni Selector`.

##### Model

I do have the model and what do I need to add as a `prop` since I do have this in the code `return ValidationHelper.GetString(GetValue("TestimonialCards"), @"");`. Should I add for example `List<TestimonialCards>` or something like that, beacuse I do also have the code for these cards that have these fields: **Icon, Title, Description**

Answer (score 0):

Kentico MVC not supported Uni Selector.

You can try with the following widget from Kentico Market place MVC Widgets - https://devnet.kentico.com/marketplace

Repeater - https://devnet.kentico.com/marketplace/repeater

Image Card - https://devnet.kentico.com/marketplace/image%20card